# how do i avoid jquery append from repeating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i avoid append from repeating itself

```
**` return Product::owned()->where("label",  "{$name}")
        ->skip(1)->take(5)->get()->all();`**
```

my jquery is below

```
$(".search_product").keyup(function () {

        var name = $(this).val();
        $(".product_lists").empty()
        $.ajax({
           url : "{{\CLEM\Helper::route('sale_pos_getProductDataByName')}}",
            type: "post",
            data : {
               _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
                name: name,
            },
            success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
                var html = '';

               for( var i = 0 ; i <  data.stock.length ; i++)
               {

                   $(".product_lists").empty()
                   html += ('<div class="col-xs-2">' +
               ' <button title="'+data.stock[i].label+'" id="'+data.stock[i].code+'" value="'+data.stock[i].code+'" type="button" class="img-thumbnail btn-default product add_pro_menu pos-tip" data-container="body"> ' +
                       '<table>' +
                       ' <tr> <td>'+data.stock[i].label+'</td> ' +
                       '</tr> <tr> <td> <img src="{{Helper::assetUrl('/uploads').'/'}}'+data.stock[i].image_url+'" alt="" style="width:60px;height:60px; text-align: center" class="img-circle img-responsive img-thumbnail"/> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>Qty: '+data.stock[i].quantity+'</td> </tr> <tr> <td> Price: {{\CLEM\Helper::getDefaultCurrency()}}'+data.stock[i].price+'</td> ' +
                       '</tr> </table>' +
                       ' </button> ' +
                       '</div>')

               }
                $(".product_lists").prepend(html)
            }
        });
    });
```

### when the code runs it repeats the set of of product twice

i.e i expect 5 items on the list but i get 10 items on the list i donot know what the problem is. any help would be appreciated

Comment: How many items are in array `data.stock` in your browser console? My bet is there are 10 and it sounds more like a back end problem ... OR ... you have more than one `$(".product_lists")`

Comment: I found the problem. thanks,  $(".product_lists") was inside another loop